# connect to database using JDBC in java

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using JDBC Driver and I'm handle with an error: "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified".

My code is the following:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class L9
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         try
         {
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin;@localhost:1521:xe","user","password");
              Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table");
              while(rs.next())
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " "+rs.getString(2)+ " "+rs.getString(3));
              con.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println(e);
          }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Replace the `;` after the `thin` with a `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

instead of

```
jdbc:oracle:thin;@localhost:1521:xe
```

(note the : after the "thin")

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use a long format connection URL where you have the ability to pass connection descriptors. Easy Connection URL (jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/myorcldbservicename) ) does establish the connection but does not provide any High Availability capabilities.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))